# Force a language prefix in the url with Sitecore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7

Is there a setting to force the language in the URL? Like, if I browse to http://www.site.com, I should be redirected to http://www.site.com/en, as it is now I can see the start page without the language prefix.

The `LinkManager` is configured to always put in the prefix so all the links look fine at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to use is our [SEO Friendly URL Module](http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2013/05/sitecore-seo-friendly-url-module).

This module implements a custom `LinkProvider` that provides SEO Friendly URL's and forces items to be accessed through their friendly URL.
So if an item is accessed without the language code in the URL (e.g. `/my-item`) the module will 301 redirect to the URL with language code (e.g. `/en/my-item`).
That is, if you have configured it to force friendly URL's (`forceFriendlyUrl="true"`) and set `languageEmbedding="always"`.

We use that module on our [corporate website](http://www.partechit.nl), so take a look at that to see it in action.

Comment: Is there a config for allowing trailing slashes?

Comment: Hi Mikael, I have added the option to configure how trailing slashes are handled and put this in release 1.0.4. It's available on GitHub right now: https://github.com/ParTech/Seo-Friendly-Url

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ISS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to redirect / to /en

Install that module on the IIS, and setup a rule.
It can be done from the IIS gui or from web.config

I am using this rule to do the same.

Insert the following configuration in the system.webServer section in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rule name="redirert / to en" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/en/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

It will redirect every request hitten "/" to "/en"

Comment: Of course this is technically wrong, since it fails to account for `Accept-Language`.